# Tray Icon not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon, trayicon, .net-4.7.2

I have added a tray icon to my program that should show the up and have buttons for toggling certain functionality. However, the tray icon is not showing up.

I have checked that `System.Windows.Forms` is included, that the `Application.Run()` method is called after creating the tray icon, that the `Visible` property of the `NotifyIcon` object is set to true, that the Icon property is set correctly (tried several different ones, SystemIcons, my application icon, a specified file), and that the Text property is set properly.

I have looked at various SO questions & answers to no avail, it's a Windows Application targeting `.NET Framework 4.7.2`, it does not utilize a form if that matters.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SomethingSomething
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // Start the webserver
            StartWebServer().Wait();

            // Create the tray icon
            CreateTrayIcon();

            // Needed for tray icon
            Application.Run();
        }

        static void CreateTrayIcon()
        {
            trayIcon = new NotifyIcon
            {
                Visible = true,
                Icon = SystemIcons.Information,
                Text = "Current Song" + currentSong
            };

            var menu = new ContextMenu();
            var toggleRPCMenuItem = new MenuItem("Toggle RPC", (s, e) => ToggleRPC());
            var toggleAdsMenuItem = new MenuItem("Toggle Ads", (s, e) => ToggleAds());
            var exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit", (s, e) => Exit());
            menu.MenuItems.Add(toggleRPCMenuItem);
            menu.MenuItems.Add(toggleAdsMenuItem);
            menu.MenuItems.Add(exitMenuItem);
            trayIcon.ContextMenu = menu;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the trayicon and context menu in `Program` anyway?  It's much easier to do all this from the WinForms designer and ensures it is pumped correctly.  You can always make your main window invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a method that ran before `CreateTrayIcon();`:

```
StartWebServer().Wait();
```

Which blocks the rest of the code.

Comment: So what did you do?  End up removing the WS entirely or did you remove the `Wait()`.  If the latter, does the WS still function?

Comment: I removed .Wait(); and yes, it still functions.